# How to use control characters in XSL

Tags: html, xslt, button, escaping, ascii

I'm trying to use xsl to get the following html

```
<input type="button" value="line1&#10;line2">
```

I tried the following

```
<input type="button">
    <xsl:attribute name="value">
        <xsl:value-of select="'line1&#10;line2'" />
    </xsl:attribute>
</input>
```

but it is not working.

EDIT: It probably wasn't working because of my IDE's (LANSA) xsl editor. I ended up using the following xsl

```
<input type="button">
<xsl:attribute name="value">  line1
line2</xsl:attribute>
</input>
```

to generate the following html

```
<input type="button" value="line1
line2">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I don't see any problem -- both of the following transformations:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <input type="button" value="line1&#10;line2"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**and**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <input type="button">
   <xsl:attribute name="value">line1&#10;line2</xsl:attribute>
  </input>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the following XML document with any of the 11 different XSLT processors I am using:**

```
<t/>
```

**produce**:

```
<input type="button" value="line1&#xA;line2"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm guessing it is the IDE (LANSA) that is not letting me use control characters.